# Transposing user input data, Shiny is very slow

Tags: r, shiny

For my shiny App, the first step is read the user input csv file and transpose some columns of it. I have to work on this transposed data for my rest of the work. When I ran the code with a data table of size 15000 x 28, it took closer to 10 min to process. The file size is only 1mb. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I am really new at so any help on this will be very helpful.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Choose observation precipitation CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('transtab')
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
output$transtab <- renderTable({
  infile = input$file
  if(is.null(infile))
    return(NULL)
  A <- read.csv(infile$datapath,header=input$header)
  t(as.matrix(A[,5:28]))
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: t() is actually a really fast function. I would rather think that shiny does not like rendering 15000 columns of data

Comment: Is there any other way? Based on the station chosen, the number of rows may be more than 15000 in some cases. I need to be able to work with that.

Comment: How would you imagine such a massive table to look like rendered in a ShinyApp?

Comment: 15000 rows are in the original data right? But after transposing that would be 15000 columns. If you want to render a table with a high amount of rows you should be fine but rendering 15000 columns is just too much for Shiny

Comment: I think I got it now. I tried adding a plot of the table, instead of the table, the results are faster. Thank you